# How to increase heap memory in pandoc execution?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I am working on converting docx to epub.  Document contains lot of images.  When execution of converting, i have error:

```
 “pandoc.exe: Heap exhausted; Current maximum heap size is 1073741824 
   bytes (1024 MB); use `+RTS -M' to increase it. 
   Error while executing job!”
```

I am using Node.js.

Can any one assist me how to increase heap size?

Update:

```
I have increased size till 2GB.  But pandoc still shows error 
"Pandoc.exe out of memory"
```

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: might be a bug in pandoc... what version of pandoc are you using on what platform? can you reproduce with the newest version? what exactly is the input markdown? what's the smallest input you can reproduce this with?

Comment: I am using pandoc.exe 1.13.2 in windows 7 with node.js.

Comment: can you try the newest version and tell us: what exactly is the input markdown? what's the smallest input you can reproduce this with?

Comment: I will try.  Normally it is working fine.   Because of many images, it shows error. Small input conversion is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the memory available to pandoc, to say `2048 MB`, with:

```
pandoc.exe +RTS -M2048
```

But the underlying problem is probably that Pandoc uses [zip-archive](https://github.com/jgm/zip-archive) to zip the EPUB file. It seems you currently need at least as much memory as the uncompressed EPUB you want to generate (but I'd verify this before filing a bug report there).

You probably also should scale down your images a bit since 2GB seems rather excessive for an e-book (even if it's a bit smaller when compressed).

Comment: Got issue: size outside allowed  range.

Comment: @Vanarajan If you're on Windows, there's a limit of 2GB. You can increase it with [these instructions](https://jonathanchang.org/coding/fixing-pandoc-out-of-memory-errors-on-windows/).