# Issues converting larger HTML files to docx in pypandoc (pandoc)

Tags: python, html, haskell, pandoc

My question is related to [How to increase heap memory in pandoc execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704736/how-to-increase-heap-memory-in-pandoc-execution), but adds a Python-specific component.

Background: I'm trying to generate scientific reports automatically.  I've written data to an HTML file, and I'd like to use Pandoc.exe (a file conversion program) to convert to a .docx Word Document.  I've got the process to work for a smaller HTML file with an image, table, ect. That file was 307KB.

The problem starts when I try to convert a larger file (~4.5MB) with multiple graphs embedded.  I've been using `pypandoc` to convert, like this:

```
import pypandoc
PANDOC_PATH = r"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc"

infile = savepath + os.sep + 'Results ' + name + '.html'
outfile = savepath + os.sep + 'Results ' + name + '.docx'

output = pypandoc.convert(source=infile, format='html', to='docx', \
outputfile=outfile, extra_args=["+RTS", "-K64m", "-RTS"])
```

But I get a variety of errors.  Usually:

```
RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "2" during conversion: 
b"Stack space overflow: current size 33692 bytes.\nUse `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.\n"
```

or if I crank the value of -Ksize up to 256m, something like this:

```
RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "1" during conversion: b'pandoc: out of memory\r\n'
```

---

**Can someone explain what is happening, here, and some way I can get around this difficulty?**  One solution I've thought about is making my images a lot smaller.  I've just been scaling down the (80 - 500KB) originals like this, where the width and the height of each image is dependent on it's original dimensions:

```
data_uri = base64.b64encode(open(formats[graph][0], 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')

img_tag = ('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{0}" height='+formats[graph][2][0]+'
             width='+formats[graph][2][1]+'>').format(data_uri)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't explain why this happens (the 'what' is pretty obvious - the program attempts to use more memory than is available to it) but you can try getting around it by also increasing the maximum size of the heap, e.g. add `-M2GB` to `extra_args`.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion... I wish I could verify if it works or not... unfortunately I run into another error:  `RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "1" during conversion: b"pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\\x91': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream\n"`

Comment: Maybe something that has to do with the embedded pictures?

Comment: why would you embed the images instead of putting them in a directory and reference them? this is a hack that increases file size (and pandoc memory consumption) considerably...

Comment: @mb21 tried directly referencing them, but pandoc has trouble finding the files and the conversion fails.  still trying to work on this task, so thoughts are very welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks very much to help from [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038) on this one!

Two fixes finally allowed me to convert my larger HTML file to a docx file with `pypandoc`:

The first, as suggested, was

> increasing the maximum size of the heap, e.g. add -M2GB to extra_args

That is:

`output = pypandoc.convert(source=infile, format='html', to='docx', 
outputfile=outfile, extra_args=["-M2GB", "+RTS", "-K64m", "-RTS"])`

---

After increasing the heap size, I still had a second problem, so I wasn't sure if the solution worked.  Python returned an error message like this:

> RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "1" during conversion: b"pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\x91': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream\n"

Which was fixed by changing how the html file was opened in the first place.
Setting the `encoding` keyword argument to `'utf8'` allows for the conversion to work:

```
report = open(savepath + os.sep + 'Results ' + name + '.html', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```