# Increasing pandoc memory allocation using mapview in R

Tags: r, pandoc, r-mapview

I'm trying to export my mapview in R using built-in mapview-function called mapshot.
I get this error message:

> pandoc.exe: Out of memory
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 251
>
> In addition: Warning message:
> running command 'C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS ...

How do I increase the Pandoc memory size permanently in R without using a Rmarkdown-file?

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit Windows?

Comment: 64-bit and 20GB of ram.

Comment: What function are you calling (i.e. can you provide more of an example)? Also, you should consider posting this as an issue to the pkg github. Ask them to make this a parameter (depending on what function you're calling).  You may be able to pass these params to `knit_print()` if you're calling that directly or indirectly.

Comment: not familiar with R, but it calls `exec_command "pandoc"` or something similar, and there you need it to pass e.g. `pandoc +RTS -M2048` to increase the haskell runtime memory to 2048MBs... also try scaling down images before using them in your markdown document... see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704736/

Comment: I'm trying to call: `mapview(testmap, burst=T, zcol=c("x", "y", "z"), alpha.regions = "0.4", legend=T, layer.name=c("x","y","z"))` After this I can export this mapview from Rstudio using the built-in export-tool, i.e. create a standalone html file OR I can use function `mapshot(m, url=paste0(getwd(), "/heatmap.html"))`. `m` being the mapview I created.

Answer (score -1):

I got this working for my case, I did not use mapshot. My solution uses

````
```{r mappImage,screenshot.force = TRUE}
````

for the chunks where I need to replace the interactive map with an png image. The screenshot.force=TRUE option uses webshot and phantomJS( webshot::install_phantomjs() ) in the background.

Answer (score -1):

I commented out the `install.packages` operations to avoid memory overload. The implementation of this idea worked. However, some output was slightly different.